# Which timeout is used in JTA transaction

Tags: java, transactions, weblogic, jta

I have method annotated:

```
@Transactional(timeout = 600)
```

and then in weblogic server configuration I have set JTA timeout to 60s. So which timeout will be used in this procedure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose, for all `@Transactional` methods/classes where no timeout is specified, the weblogic's default of 60 is taken. If you specify a timeout T (like in your example), than that one is taken. So in your case for that method it would be 600.

Comment: yes I know which timetout is used when I didnt set it as parameter but you didnt answer to my question.

Comment: ok thx now it is clear. You are 100 % sure ? Can you post some link where this situation is described

Comment: I am pretty sure, as it is similar with JBoss, but I didn't test it. You could test it pretty simple: 1. lower weblogic's timeout to 3 seconds. 2. Set the method's timeout to 60 and in the method take the crt. time and make a while loop, in which iteration checking whether 50 seconds passed. If no TransactionTimeoutException is thrown, that the @Transactional annotation overwrites weblogic's default.